# How to use glEventHub in angular components

Tags: angular, events, golden-layout

It's possible to use glEventHub in Reactjs to manipulate tabs with regard design changes and other events as well, which I could not achieve in angular.

Reactjs Example:

```
let config={...}
var myLayout = new GoldenLayout( config );
  myLayout.registerComponent( 'Applications', Applications );
myLayout.init();


let event = this.props.glEventHub._layoutManager;
event.root.contentItems[0].contentItems[0].contentItems[1].element.hide(); 
myLayout.updateSize()

//or we can add child to the layout

let newConfig={..}
event.root.contentItems[0].contentItems[0].addChild(newConfig);
```

Please let me know how to achieve the same in angular.